# Redirecting content without changing url in htaccess file

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

On our Wordpress, we want our urls to point :

- **from** mysite/education/somethingelse
- **to** mysite/somethingelse

**But** without changing the urls for the user.

I tried this :

```
RewriteRule ^education/(.*) /$1 [R=301]
```

And

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} /education

RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [P]
```

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# RewriteRule ^education/(.*) /$1 [R=301]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} /education
# RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [P]
# RewriteRule /education ^$ [L]
# RewriteRule /education ^$ [R=301,NC,L]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} /education
# RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [P]
RewriteRule ^/education/(.*) /$1
</IfModule>
```

It didn't work : it redirects to the new url but it keeps changing url !

Any ideas please ?

Comment: Remove `[R=301]` from first rewrite rule and test it.

Comment: @revo thanks but i get permission denied error when I remove `[R=301]`

Comment: Then check what rejects the request.

Comment: @revo it didn't work , there is an url changing each time

Comment: It's probably another rule that is conflicting.

Comment: @revo i edit my question : I added the rules part in my file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194760/discussion-between-lamloumi-afif-and-revo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your rewrites to this rules

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^education\/(.*) /$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```